# CPU accessing instructions

Tags: cpu, counter

I don't understand how the CPU knows when it needs to point or look at a certain location where some machine format of instruction is stored? Precisely, I don't know how the CPU knows which memory location it need to put in Program Counter (Instruction Set) before it actually starts executing that particular instruction. I hope that this question is not too confusing because a I am lost :D

Comment: I think this question is too broad. This is a rather lengthy and complex topic to describe. I would research program counter and read up on it a bit. If you find something more specific to ask, you could then make a new question.

Comment: I was afraid that It was too broad, I will try to reasarch as you say.

Comment: It makes for a very interesting read, but can be confusing based on the knowledge someone has. From my personal experience, I learned how it worked by taking classes in computer architecture, assembly programming and operating systems. Computer architecture is where I was taught how it works, having assembly and OS was just a bonus for myself. Here is material on the [PC (Program Counter) and IR (Instruction Register)](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Overall/pc_ir.html). It's brief, but I think enough to help you know what to start with.

Comment: The CPU knows because of the CPU instruction its currently processing.  You should do some more research and edit this question.

Comment: Yes its interesting, and your material is right Program Counter is poor name for what Program Counter does xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't know how the CPU knows which memory location it need to put in Program Counter (Instruction Set) before it actually starts executing that particular instruction.

Actually it's not that complicated.
The Program Counter (aka PC) register contains the memory address of the (next) instruction to (fetch and) execute.
(Assuming that we're using a CPU with stack architecture.)

- On a processor reset (e.g. after a power-on), the PC is automatically loaded with a predefined address, which is expected to be the location of the first instruction of a bootstrap program.
- When the instruction being executed is any kind of branch, jump, or call operation, then the target address is calculated, and loaded into the PC register.  The next instruction is (fetched and) executed from that target address.
- When the instruction being executed is a return operation, then the return address is popped off the stack, and loaded into the PC register.  The next instruction is (fetched and) executed from that return address.
- For all other instructions, the PC register is simply incremented (i.e. "*counts*") to advance to the next instruction in memory.  That is, the instructions are (fetched and) executed sequentially (until a branching-type of instruction is executed or an interrupt occurs).
- If an interrupt occurs, then when the current instruction completes, the contents of the updated PC register is pushed onto the stack (for later use as a return address).  The PC register is loaded with the address of an interrupt handler, which is then executed.

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found the answer. At very beginning CPU gets initialization address of our application when our application is started, for example that address is typically 0x00000000 for 32-bit infrastructure, after that initial micro-program starts and based on initialization address he supplies program counter with memory location where instruction is stored. 
Just to say, I am sorry because I post complex question here before I done research. I hope that someone will found this useful.